# Unable to process data from push notification in IOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have set up everything and i do receive a push notification but I am unable to process it. i.e I want a pop up window to show together when i receive the message. The pop
As the notification is received i want to use this function  `retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message.data)!, context);` to get the data in the notification and build a  pop up window. On IOS i get `Null check operator used on a null value` at `(message.data)!`

This is the `getRideRequestId` function

```
String? getRideRequestId(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    String? rideRequestId = "";

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      // print();
      rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
      print("This is ride request ID :$rideRequestId");
    } else {
      //for ios
      rideRequestId = message['data'];
    }
    //doublenotification++;
    return rideRequestId;
  }
```

In android it works fine but in Ios I get an error `Null check operator used on a null value` This is at  `retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message.data)!, context);`

This is How i send the notification from another device, Is it correct ror ios ?

```
static sendNotificationToDriver(
      String token, context, String rideRequestId) async {
    try {
      await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Authorization': serverToken,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "to": token,
          "collapse_key": "type_a",
          "notification": {
            "body": "Nepali Rider",
            "title": "You have a new Ride"
          },
          "data": {"ride_request_id": rideRequestId}
        }),
      );
      print('FCM request for device sent!');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    print("ride request id :$rideRequestId");
    print("ride request id :$token");
    print(jsonEncode);
  }
```

Comment: your argument is same. but the key is different. ofcourse it will null. see android : `message['ride_request_id']`  , iOS : `message['data']`

Comment: Thanx! Unable to mark your answer solved tho as its a comment.